# Win32 Excel: Resize image to cell maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: excel, image, winapi, xlsx, pywin32

I'm writing a script that given an image and its containing cell should resize the image to fit that cell while preserving it's aspect ratio.

The function takes 3 parameters, the image, the width of the cell and the height of the cell.

I've written the following function so far:

```
def fitToCell(img, width, height):
    ratioX = width / img.Width
    ratioY = height / img.Height

    if ratioX * img.Height > height:
        ratio = ratioY
    else:
        ratio = ratioX

    img.Width = img.Width * ratio
    img.Height = img.Height * ratio

    return img
```

My logging gives me the following result:

```
Original Image: (48.0, 35.26598358154297)
Desired Image: (100, 100)
Ratios: (2.0833333333333335, 2.8355936753834547)
Final Ratio: 2.0833333333333335
Final Image: (208.33331298828125, 153.0640869140625)
```

This doesnt seem to make any sense to me as 2 * 48 = 96, not 208. The ratio should produce the output 100, 73.

I'm using the win32com api with Python on xlsx files. I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: When I ran your code on my computer, I found that except `img. Width = img. Width * ratio

Img. Height = img. Height * ratio `reports `AttributeError:` Except for the error (which may be the cause of my compilation environment), I replaced the two lines above with `Width = img. width * ratio

Height = img. height * ratio`, and print out the values of `Width` and  `Height`. The result is correct as expected.

Comment: Thats strange as the documentation states that methods are capitalised, I get an attribute error when I try and use lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my modified code, which can achieve the desired results.

My build environment is WIN10, python 3.7

```
from PIL import Image 

def fitToCell(img, width, height):
  try:    
    ratioX = width / img.width
    ratioY = height / img.height

    if ratioX * img.height > height:
        ratio = ratioY
    else:
        ratio = ratioX

    Width = img.width * ratio
    Height = img.height * ratio

    print("Original Image :",img.width, img.height)
    print("Ratios :",ratioX, ratioY)
    print("Final Ratio :",ratio)
    print("Final Image :",Width, Height)
  except IOError: 
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__": 
  img  = Image.open("panda.jpg")
  fitToCell(img, 400, 400)
```

Debug Result:

```
Original Image : 268 304
Ratios : 1.492537313432836 1.3157894736842106
Final Ratio : 1.3157894736842106
Final Image : 352.63157894736844 400.0
```

The difference is that I use the [image module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html).

> The Image module provides a class with the same name which is used to
>   represent a PIL image. The module also provides a number of factory
>   functions, including functions to load images from files, and to
>   create new images.